# how to call javascript function after loading angularjs element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to call java script function aftter loading div please help me
 to call javascript function after loading angularjs element

```
 <div id="teset" ng-load="getAngularValue()">venn {{test}}</div>


function getAngularValue(){
alert("getAngularValue");

}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean *"aftter loading div"*..? are you loading content into this div, or do you mean after div is loaded in DOM..? Are you using some plugin..?

Comment: after loading div i need to call javascript funciton

Comment: That is the same thing you've mentioned in question. It is not clear what that means

Comment: What do you want to achieve basically when you call that function? We can point you in right direction if you provide details.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want call `javascript` function inside `angularjs`?

Upto my knowledge you can do a lot of work inside `angularjs` controller.

```
<div id="teset" ng-init="getAngularValue()">venn {{test}}</div>

<script>
    angular.module('demoApp').controller('demoCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.getAngularValue = function(){
              //todo logic
              alert("getAngularValue");
        };
    });
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use ng-load, your function must be placed in Angualr controller

[This link](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) schould help you: